# Plot border color change

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, figure

How can I change border color from dark gray to white? I have tried a few things but not success.

here is code and figure.

[Image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5z9j.png)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('classic')
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
import pylab as plt2

def plot_hist(*argv, titles):
  """
  plots the historgram of the input phase maps
  """
  for i in range(len(argv)):
      hist = np.histogram(argv[i].ravel(), bins=100)
      plt.plot(hist[1][1:], hist[0])
  plt.xlabel("phase values")
  plt.ylabel("frequency")
  plt.title("Histogram Analysis")
  plt.grid()
  if titles is not None:
    plt.legend(titles) 
  fig=plt.figure(facecolor='white') 
  plt.show()
```

I tried to change facecolor to white but it did not work.

Comment: remove `plt.style.use('classic')` which changes the border colour.

Comment: or alternatively this: `plt.rcParams['figure.facecolor']='white'` to overwrite the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actively setting the style to `classic`, which sets `figure.facecolor` to grey (see the style parameters on [github](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/a861b8af82cc4618e0a631e5eac5b4030b3f04a1/lib/matplotlib/mpl-data/stylelib/classic.mplstyle#L2)). Is this on purpose?

You can either remove `plt.style.use('classic')` to use the default style or set `figure.facecolor` to white with the following:

```py
plt.rcParams['figure.facecolor']='white'
```